# Sliding from right to left vertical Menu > Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

Hi guys i want my vertical menu to be slided from right to left. But as far as i have come with jquery is with .toggle() (and this is from top to bottom sliding)
I want when clicked on hamburger menu the menu to be slided from right to left. If any1 can help me i would really aprreaciate

I dont have any code tried with jquery for sliding from right to left, i have only tried with .toggle

```css
.ham-menu{
    width: 35px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ham-menu .line{
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 3px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.first-section{
    padding: 0;
}
.first-section .slide-menu{
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.list-menu{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.list-menu li{
    margin: 20px;
}
.list-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ham-menu">
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <span class="line"></span>
</div>

<div class="first-section container-fluid">
        <div class="slide-menu">
            <ul class="list-menu animated">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Footer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpEdPa)

```
.first-section{
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.ham-menu').click(function(){
  $('.first-section').toggle();
})
```

Comment: Not exactly..The vertical div is display: none and when clicked on the hamburger menu to be slided from right to left. I didnt hide the vertical div with display: none, so you can view that exists

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check if this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, i will proceed for some animation, thank you very much